# How to upgrade from 8.04 (hardy heron) to the latest upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I have a compaq Presario R3000 running hardy heron 8.04 with gnome.

I want to update to the latest version, but i am having a bit of trouble.

I've tried using Update Manager but when I try to upgrade to 10.04.4 (which is the only option) it says that it is no longer supported, but i keep going, and it starts downloading stuff then prepares to upgrade, but then when i gets to "setting new software channels" it gives an error.

I don't know how to boot off a usb.

Answer (score 1):

You should install anew. Yes, there is a procedure on how to update the Ubuntu that old to a new one. But you need to be an experienced linux user to solve the problems that arise.
So - back up the data you need and install Ubuntu from zero up, with erasing and formatting the partition you want to install it to.